# GUI on ubuntu server

Tags: server, gui

Just finished installation of Server. Logged into a command line. Was expecting a GUI interface. How do i configure a GUI like KDE or Gnome to manage my server??

Comment: What do you plan to manage in a server using GUI? You will find nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI is not included in the server version. Log in to the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lightweight version:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```